# proportion Div and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, r

I would like to know how I can proportion image and text  inside a div. lets say I have a div that is 8 inches by 7 inches (scale down to fit inside container width: 490px; height: 500px;) what I want to do is resize the images and text using inches instead of "px" and I want he text and image to be proportion to my 8X7 inch div. I don't want to have 3 inch images that are bigger than my div. if I say I want 3 inch image I want their to be space like in real life. I know its hard to understand please ask more questions if you are not sure what I'm talking about thank you for your time

Comment: You should work with % values, you should at least try to come up with some code example, or a picture of what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually resize the div, image or text. You need to check your div using the "border: 1px solid red" in your CSS. You'll see the div border appear, maybe your text or image doesn't have space because they're just fitting all together inside the div without any space that looks squeezing each other. So you need to resize your div if you want to have more space inside it. Sorry I'm also having a hard time understanding your question. I hope I answered your question